# Magento: how to retrieve deleted tax_class

Tags: php, html, database, magento, phpmyadmin

i have a slight problem here.
i am using stock in the channel with magento, and there plugin uses magento's default tax_class_id.

but the problem we are facing is we have deleted the default magento tax class id.

we have tried to change the plugin to make it use our custom tax_class_id. but as soon we do that plugin dont work.

we have tried to create the same name tax_class but it dont work as it use the new tax_class_id which is now 11.

can we make magento retrieve the deleted tax_class_id?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Magento, but it sounds like the problem is you deleted a row of data from the tax_class_id table, and when you try to recreate it you get a different value for the auto incrementing primary key tax_class_id, which if I'm correctly reading what you wrote, is confusingly the name of both the table and one of the columns in that table. Not that it matters what they're called, you can go in the tax_class_id table, create a new row, and then double-click on the tax_class_id column to edit the value there to make it match the original value (provided you know what the original value was, of course, but looking in whatever tables reference that value should give you that answer if you don't know). So basically just create it as you've done, it will automatically assign a new counter ID but you can edit that through phpMyAdmin.

Note that, in general, messing with auto incrementing ID values and changing existing data is a good way to mess up your referential integrity, but as long as you have a good backup and understand what you're doing this should work fine for you.